# An unexpected error occurred while signing in. Failure, in Mojave

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update, mojave

Installed Mojave (10.14 (18A391)) this week from App Store in High Sierra.

Now I was gonna perform a software update, but as soon as I startd the App Store it asks me to sign in, and when I press "Sign in", I'll see this page:

[image]

I've tried (and restarting after each step):

- Clearing some cache-files for appstore and appstore agent:

  rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore
  rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.storeagent
  rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist
  rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.storeagent.plist
  rm ~/Library/Cookies/com.apple.appstore.plist
- Add trust to some Apple Developer certificate in the App Store
- Cleared /var/db/crls/
- Cleared "System Integrity" (`csrutil status`)

Any other potential ways to solve this? I really need to update my Xcode.

(I see more people struggling with this here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8552241)

Comment: create new user and try

Comment: @Buscar웃 I created a new user on the mac, then I could enter credentials in the app store, but wouldnt be "logged" in anyway. I had to keep re-entering it, and it didnt say anything was wrong, but never actually got logged int..